# read data from a structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

I have to load some data in a structure.

I do it inside a function.

assuming that my structure is called

`loaddata`

and the data are in

`loaddata.corrected_data`

how can I access to it within a function?

```
function loaddata_struct(path,namestruct)
  loaddata = load(path);
  data = loaddata.corrected_data; % this should change depending on the argument of the function (namestruct in this case)
end
```

how can I pass the name of the structure? in this case corrected_data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return the structure's field with the name passed to loaddata_struct function:

```
function data = loaddata_struct(path,namestruct)
  loaddata = load(path);
  data = loaddata.(namestruct);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic field names like so:

```
fieldOfInterest = 'corrected_data';

data = loaddata.(fieldOfInterest);
```

If you're loading from file, you can also access the data directly

```
data = load('theDataFile.mat','-mat',fieldOfInterest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`getfield`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html)** and if you need to work on a `1 x N` sized struct array -

```
function loaddata_struct(path,fname)

loaddata = load(path);
for k1 = 1:numel(loaddata)
    data{k1} = getfield(loaddata(k1),fname);
end

return;
```

Thus, you can use it like this - `loaddata_struct(path,'corrected_data')`

Comment: is it possible to use genvarname?

Comment: @gabboshow You mean a generic function code where we can change the fieldname?

Comment: yes...anyway the answer of ymihere is the one that I was looking for...I didn't know you could access like this..

Comment: @gabboshow I have used a loop to account for `1 x N` sized array, just to keep it *generic*.

Answer (score -1):

Do it as text and use [`isfield`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html) and [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eval.html). `Isfield` will check if the string is a field of the struct, and if it is, then use eval to evaluate `loaddata.fieldname`. Using isfield you make sure you never get an error, and you can do things in the else, like finding the data that has the most similar name to the one inserted, for example.

```
function loaddata_struct(path,fieldname)
  loaddata = load(path);
  if isfield(loaddata ,fieldname)
     data = eval(strcat('loaddata.',fieldname));
  else
     error('Heeey mate, thats not a field')
  end
end
```